# How can I include a CSS file in one PHP file, when all of my PHP files use a common header include?

Tags: php, css

I have a common HTML header file which I use in several PHP files. I have a general CSS file which I have included inside the `<head>` tags in the header file. However, I want to include one additional CSS file only in one PHP file. Since I have common header file, do I have to include the additional CSS file in the common header or there is any way that I can include the additional CSS file *only* in the PHP file where it is required?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that common header include file, use a conditional statement (if) and depending on the condition, place the link to the stylesheet.

Example:

```
<?php
if($somevar){
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">';
}
?>
```

The `$somevar` is your condition.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why a lot of people include a piece of code in their header files that allow you to add more stylesheets to it on a per-page basis.

Something like this (goes in **<head>**):

```
<?php
if (!empty($styles) && is_array($styles)) {
    foreach ($styles AS $style) {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/'. $style .'">';
    }
}
?>
```

You could expand on that if you wanted to include media types, but that snippet allows you to put a variable at the top of an individual script if you need a specific stylesheet:

```
<?php
$styles = array('custom_style.css');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your-specified.css">';
```

in your desired PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to set a special class on the body on your page and use CSS selectors accordingly in only ONE CSS file:

```
<body class="<?php echo $pageName; ?>">
```

If your special page is "special", then use in the CSS:

```
body.special h2 {...}
```

It will override your common h2 declaration.

Much more easier to maintain if the changes in this special page are minor.